# How to only display items created by the current logged in user only in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

As the question says I'm trying to figure out exactly how I would make it so when a user logs in they only see the data entries they have entered into the database. I used the ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View_Controller) template to start.

```
public class Item
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Power { get; set; }
    public string Charges { get; set; }

    public Item(){

       

    }

}
```

This is the data in question, the items model. My initial thought was that I need a one to many relationship between the AspNetUsers table and the Items table and then change something in the items controller, but I'm not entirely sure how/if I can make edits to the AspNetUsers table.

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ItemsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Items
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        //Return a list to the view
        return View(await _context.Item.ToListAsync());
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchItems()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSearchResults(String SearchPhrase)
    {
        //Return a list from index where 
        return View("Index", await _context.Item.Where(j => j.Name.Contains(SearchPhrase)).ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Items/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var item = await _context.Item
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(item);
    }

    // GET: Items/Create
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Items/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,Power,Charges")] Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(item);
    }

    // GET: Items/Edit/5
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var item = await _context.Item.FindAsync(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(item);
    }

    // POST: Items/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,Description,Power,Charges")] Item item)
    {
        if (id != item.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(item);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ItemExists(item.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(item);
    }

    // GET: Items/Delete/5
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var item = await _context.Item
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(item);
    }

    // POST: Items/Delete/5
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var item = await _context.Item.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Item.Remove(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool ItemExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Item.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
```

This is the items controller. If I need to give more information I can.

Comment: Why would you need to modify the AspNetUsers table? Each item can only be owned by one user right? So your item table needs a UserId column that is a foreign key reference back to the AspNetUsers table.

Comment: You should tackle this one thing at a time. What view are you talking about? The `Index` view? If so, don't post all the update / create / delete methods, they just confuse the point. At the moment, it looks like the `Index` controller action is returning all records in the `Item` table. You need to figure out the current user, and then query the table to only return records for that user.

Comment: Steps should be, Firstly, when you are creating `item` it should also log `created_by` which should be a `userId` . secondly, once the user logged in you should have `user login id` once you have it then call a the item list where `created_by` equals to your logged in `userId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I'm not entirely sure how/if I can make edits to the AspNetUsers table.

You can inherit from `IdentityUser` to custom user data.

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Power { get; set; }
    public string Charges { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ItemsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Items
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = await _context.Item
                            .Where(a => a.ApplicationUser.Id == HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value)
                            .ToListAsync();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Item { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Update `Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml` and replace `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Where can I actually see the application users in the database, because when I look there are no items in the AspNetUsers table anymore. Also when I create an item in the items table it seems to have a null ApplicationUserId.

Comment: Be sure you have rerun `add-migration` and `update-database`. Then be sure you have register the User. Besides, for create an item in items with ApplicationId, you need post a new thread. For this thread issue, it has been solved, you can hard coded ApplicationId to test my data.

Comment: Alright I got it to work finally. In the create method in the controller I assigned the current user manually using `var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

                ApplicationUser applicationUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

                item.ApplicationUser = applicationUser;`